# Basic accumulator program

Tags: assembly

I just started a computer science course in high school and we received vague instructions on assembly and the accumulator. This is a part of a program that I need to trace the output for (input values are 40 and 24):

```
001 IN N1
002 IN N2
003 LDA N1
004 MUL N2
005 STA PR
006 LDA N2
007 CMP #0
008 JEQ 011
```

and it goes on. I understand what is happening from 001-006, but after that I get stuck on CMP and JEQ. At 006 the accumulator loads N2, which is 24, but the next step is CMP, which upon Googling I found out was to compare two values using subtraction. I'm not sure what to do when there is just #0. For 008, JEQ means jump if equal, so am I right to assume that it is just saying "if n2 is equal to N2, jump to 011 and then continue from there"?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CMP in that sort of assembly will generally compare a value to the argument, /and set a flag/ if it matches.   Then JEQ will jump if that flag is set.

If you told me what your target processor is, I could be a lot more precise about it, and even use correct terminology, etc.  =)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't think my teacher ever told us what the target processor is. She just introduced these operations by definition and told us to trace the program. So CMP compares N2 to #0? What exactly is #0?

Comment: I believe #0 is "immediate zero".  The # means the number literally as it is (0) and not a reference to some other place to find the value.  So, you're comparing to #0 "the number zero".